# R: statistics on timevalues

Tags: r, time

I have a series of time values in a vector:

```
# Source data in %m:%s"
>intervals <- c("1:30", "1:33", "1:29", "1:31", "1:30")
```

If I want to average these values then I can use the `strptime()` function:

```
# Averaging with strptime()
> meantime <- mean(strptime(intervals,"%M:%S"))
> meantime
[1] "2013-11-01 00:01:30 PDT"
```

But I don't need the date and timezone stuff. And I have problems, when I want to do further calculations with that time value. Let's say, these time values belongs to a distance of 400 m long race track. Let's calculate the average speed and pace:

```
> distance <- as.numeric(400)
> distance
[1] 400
> # Let's calculate the average speed:
> distance/meantime
Error in Ops.POSIXt(distance, meantime) : 
  '/' not defined for "POSIXt" objects
> # Let's calculate the average pace:
> meantime / distance
Error in Ops.POSIXt(meantime, distance) : 
  '/' not defined for "POSIXt" objects
```

So the question: is there an easy, and clean way to handle time values to do this and similar calculations?

Comment: This seems like a borderline request. You have not described this "to process" activity on "running logs" in sufficient detail, so you are asking us to idly speculate about appropriate tools. Such requests are deprecated on SO and unless you put in many further details, this question will probably be closed. You should attend to this issue promptly.

Comment: OK, I think now the question is more direct and the question is easier to understand. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difftime function will return the differences (in seconds and relative to GMT) of datetime values:

```
inters <- strptime(intervals,"%M:%S")
inters
difftime( inters , Sys.Date())
Time differences in hours
[1] 7.025000 7.025833 7.024722 7.025278 7.025000
attr(,"tzone")
[1] ""
# I appear to be 7 hours off from GMT here on the Left Coast of the US.
```

So that wasn't a easy as we might have hoped, so look at the `as.difftime` function:

```
intervals <- c("1:30", "1:33", "1:29", "1:31", "1:30")
inters <- as.difftime(intervals,"%M:%S")
inters
#
Time differences in mins
[1] 1.500000 1.550000 1.483333 1.516667 1.500000
attr(,"tzone")
[1] ""

distance=400
>     as.numeric(inters)/ distance
[1] 0.003750000 0.003875000 0.003708333 0.003791667 0.003750000
# Remembering that these are in minutes
```